# Eliminate the content on the edge of JavaScript and CSS rendering blocking

Tags: javascript, css, web

I've been testing my site at Google develop and this showed up. I tried everything, still can't find out how to fix that, can you help me please?

**Error:**

> You Should Fix: Eliminate the content on the edge of JavaScript and CSS rendering blocking.

[My website](http://www.fitness-decision.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to minify your css and javascript files and link them with the minified files file.min.js and file.min.css in your project. To minify you can use [this](http://refresh-sf.com/) tool online.